# Indulge/Kill/Satisfy my curiosity

Tags: word-choice, formality, writing-style

I have few questions for my customer and I want to say him that it is just my curiosity. What is the right sentence which I can use to deal with my customers so that they won't find it funny or offense?

- Could you please indulge my curiosity?
- Could you please kill my curiosity?
- Could you please satisfy my curiosity?

Comment: "Just out of curiosity," is a good preface for a question that lets the reader know you don't need the information. As in "Just out of curiosity, is Microsoft Excel installed on the system? Sometimes that has compatibility issues with our software".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I myself would rather use "Could you please ***appease*** my curiosity?", however, I'd say that either ***indulge*** or ***satisfy*** would be also ok. "Could you please ***kill*** my curiosity?" sounds a bit blunt to me in this context.